# windows themes are all screwed up

Tags: themes, window, text

I just upgraded to 18.04.1 and I found that i cannot read the text within the drop down menus, sub menus, and buttons. For example, I cannot read my input when i type my user name and password in websites, or the OK and CANCEL in buttons.

I've tried Unity and GNOME tweaks to change themes and settings but I can't get it to work. I also found out that in the BACKGROUND window in settings i only have two pictures, one for the background and one for the lockscreen without any options for anything else like text color etc.

The upgrade made my computer close to unusable. Any ideas of what I could do here? Keep in mind I am not a Linux Guru... more of a point and click transplant from windoze.

[image]

Comment: i've tried to post a picture but I can't figure out how to do it

Comment: When you go to signin there is a gear next to the password field. After typing your password, click the gear and change the selection from Gnome to Unity. Then click the Sign In button.

Comment: went there and i switched to Unity but the problem persists

Comment: also installed unity tweak and no dice

Comment: @thomasrutter OP has answered his own question after your comment. So we can delete our comments too.

Answer (score 1):

OK. My possible answer and one that is working right now: I had installed UBUNTU TWEAK. That gave me the option to change the WINDOW theme and the Gtk Theme(whatever that is). I set them both to Ambiance and now I can read the sub menus, menus and button functions. Whew! Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: You can set the theme to Ambiance (which is the default anyway) by going to `System Settings` -> `Appearance` and selecting `Ambiance` for theme. This in Ubuntu 16.04 anyway. Before you upgraded to 18.04 you must have changed it to a different theme. This a good thing to know for users who stray from the default path.